# How can I add a sidebar button to the actionbar like in the new google apps?

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar

How can I add one of those sidebar buttons to the actionbar like in the new google apps? I cannot find any information on it on the internet. I only found info on how to add buttons to the right of the application logo which is not what i need.

[image: This is what i mean]

Answer (score 2):

The official Google implementation is available through the latest Support Library. Here is [a link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) to more information about how to set it up.

Comment: First of all: thanks! Will this also work with custom drawers like slidingMenu? I just quickly scanned the code and it looks like a toggle for the google drawer only. I will look deeper into the code tonight.

Comment: You create the Drawer in a Layout xml and you can put in it whatever you want.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot use the drawer since it is sliding on top of the content and we need a menu that is hidden behind the content (so move the screen content to the right, rather than sliding the drawer over the content from the left). I've got the code working fine now for opening and closing the menu, currently i am looking for a way to replace the "back" arrow with a custom drawable at runtime

Comment: That's at that link as well: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon

Comment: Yes, okay let me be more clear. Since we need to support all versions until 2.1 we have to rely on ActionBarSherlock for the ActionBar. Unfortunately ActionbarSherlock does not support the methods mentioned on your link yet. I've accomplished the same effect though by listening to clicks on the android.R.home icon in the ActionBar and then toggeling the SlidingMenu. This works fine but the icon in the ActionBar is still the back-arrow and not something resembling a drawer-icon. So now I need to replace that icon live. Sorry for not being completely clear about my situation in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I've never used ActionBarSherlock. Sorry!

Comment: No worries! Your links were still super helpfull!